# How to join data from two tables in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables: `Account`, `User` and `Organization`.

- `Account` consists of `id`, `name` and `organization_id`.
- `User` consists of `email` and `organization_id`.
- `Organization` consists of `id` and `name`.

Each `Account` is registered to an `Organization`(through `organization_id`) and each `User` is registered to an `Organization`. The challenge is to display all the emails (from `User`) to the `Account` corresponding to the `name` whose `organization_id` matches the `organization_id` of `User`.

Here's my code till now:

```
class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "account"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), index=True, unique=True)
    organization = Column(Integer, 
        ForeignKey("organization.id"),nullable=False, index=True)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model, RBACUserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    organization = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("organization.id"), 
                      nullable=False, index=True)

class Organization(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "organization"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(512))
    users = relationship("User", backref="organizations")
    accounts = relationship("Account", backref="organizations")
```

Answer (score 14):

Join user and account on organization id and filter based on name:

```
db.session.query(User.email).\
    join(Account, Account.organization == User.organization).\
    filter(Account.name == 'some name')
```

[`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) allows passing arbitrary SQL expressions as the on-clause when using the 2 argument form.